# Symfony 3 Form, How to pass an array of boolean to my form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony3.x

I have an simple array of 56 Booleans in my entity, those Booleans symbolize a square in [this board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDZKI.png).
I'm stuck and don't know how to pass those boolean through a form.

**Update**:

Entity is as follow : "

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="disponibilite", type="simple_array", nullable=true)
 */
private $disponibilite;
```

And in my constructor

```
$arraydispo = [];
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 55) {
  $arraydispo[] = 0;
  $i++;
}
$this->setDisponibilite($arraydispo);
```

I'm working for a behind schedule client, and have no control over the entity, im forced to do it that way.
I've managed to send the array with a collection type but it get sent as key value and since it is not a one dimentional array I cannot use CheckBoxType

Comment: Maybe there is a design lack in your entity, so please show us your model and especially your array

Comment: @JimPanse, yeah thanks for the suggestion, updated it

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I would go for CheckboxType as it returns true if checked and null if not check, all that is left then is to handle the null value as a false.

Comment: 56 `CheckboxType`s?

Comment: Well if that's how he mapped things then he has to render 56 elements anyway.

Comment: I've managed to send all the data through a CollectionType with CheckBoxType inside, but since my array is a key->value array it does not work

Comment: Hmmm maybe this is really a special case which needs a special custom form type ... something like an input matrix table, depending on how you like to process your data in forms. However, in my opinion representing data in this way (array) seems not to be a really clean object oriented way, no matter how many data objects are represented

Comment: I 100% agree with you, and if I had more time I would redisign the entity, the only thing preventing this bit of code to work is that key value nonsence that makes it impossible to use CheckboxType, do you know a workaround ?

Comment: If you receive all the values as an array successfully, then you can map them to your array manually in the code where you process the form data.

Comment: Use expanded choice type. (=checkboxes but only one formtype field)